# Mass importing documents into Google Doc

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I'm looking for a way to import a lot of documents to Google Docs (not just uploading to drive).

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload a folder at once:

[image]

Make sure to check the settings for upload; conversion to Google Drive format, OCR of PDF files.

Comment: I actually didn't know about the conversion option :-) Found it, and it works now just fine. Thanks.